# UIWebView not loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an application with four view controllers ( four tabs ) , and I'm trying the fourth one load a url with UIWebView .. Please check the codes below

This FourthViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FourthViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

FourthViewController.m

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"


@interface FourthViewController ()

@end

@implementation FourthViewController
@synthesize webView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    //self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Instagram";
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                       target:self action:@selector(refreshClicked:)] init];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}




-(IBAction)refreshClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked");

}



- (NSString *)tabImageName
{
    return @"instagram";
}

@end
```

But when I run the iPhone Simulator and got to the Fourth tab it doesn't load the web, what is the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you do not call  your super init.  Why did you comment out this line:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

edit - also you should use "self." in front of that webView var to reference it via the property you've setup.  Not your bug, just good practice.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

And the other responder is correct - if you didn't connect your webview IBOutlet to this class; then webView things won't work, so be sure to check that.

edit 2: If you are not using interface builder, then you need to create your objects and add them to your view.

```
self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.webview]
```

Ditto for any other views/controls on this screen.  Note: IBOUTLET is just a #define that turns into nothing.  It is there so that interface builder knows which properties you might like to use as outlets.

Comment: If you are not using IB (storyboard or xib) then you should create your webview.  `self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]` before using it.

Comment: @user - I updated my answer to create the webview, size it (full screen), and stick it in your view.  That should do the trick.  For simple screens like this, you may want to consider using interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using xib, then you need to alloc-init and add it to the view hierarchy.

So, in your `viewDidLoad` method, for example:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release]; // if you don't use ARC
```

Then, if you don't use xib, you don't need to use `IBOutlet`. This is only placeholder that allows to work with Interface Builder (i.e. connect outlets).

**Edit**

You should change the code I provided like the following (for example). Mine was simply an example. That warning simply states that a local variable hides the declaration of the variable you created in .h.

```
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.webView = web;
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[web release]; // if you don't use ARC
```

Comment: Wow!, it works like a magic but there is something show for me " Local Declaration of 'webView' hides instance variable " so ?

Comment: I solved it, I remove UIWebView from header file Thanks alot guys

Comment: happy to hear this. Have a nice day. ;)

Comment: @user2104662 You are free to remove the accepted mark but when you receive replies based only on code you should also understand what they mean. Copy and paste code does not make sense. Mine was there for this. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
[self.webView addSubview:self.webview];
```

For refresh in the bar button target method `refreshClicked:`

```
- (IBAction)refreshClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the IBOutlet in your code to your Interface .xib document?

Check out [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/07/30/iphone-programming-tutorial-connecting-code-to-an-interface-builder-view/) tutorial if you don't understand.

Comment: Well I recommend them, but if you didn't, check out Dave's answer

Comment: If you're not using xib; are you using storyboard?  If no - then why the IBOutlet?

Comment: ^ @Dave Thinking the same thing.  You are either using an xib/storyboard or you have no code adding this UIWebView to the view

Comment: Okay what could I use instead of IBOutlet ?